# How to alert the category selected from jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery's `catcomplete` to return data from a db with different categories. How do I alert out the category from the value that was selected.

The below line returns `[object Object]`, not the `Catagory`

```
select: function( event, ui ) { alert(ui.item); }
```

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of the `alert()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never rely on `alert` to print anything useful. Use `console.log` instead.

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui.item.category);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ui.item.value

```
select: function( event, ui ) { alert(ui.item.value); }
```

Working JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/qpHWv/

Answer (score 0):

You should get the `Value` of the `Object`

```
alert(ui.item.value);
```